# Parsing a network address string

Tags: python, parsing

I am using python 3.5 and have a network address string like the following:

```
tcp://10.1.2.3:45678
```

I want to parse this string and extract the protocol, the ip address and the port number.

I know I can do this very easily with a string split or regex, however I was wondering if there is a python package or module that does this. I am sure that there is a specification for these string which defines them, hence I am interested in a python module instead of using regex or string parsing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are looking for `urllib.parse.urlparse`:

```
In [1050]: import urllib

In [1051]: urllib.parse.urlparse('tcp://10.1.2.3:45678')
Out[1051]: ParseResult(scheme='tcp', netloc='10.1.2.3:45678', path='', params='', query='', fragment='')

In [1052]: url = urllib.parse.urlparse('tcp://10.1.2.3:45678')

In [1053]: url.scheme
Out[1053]: 'tcp'

In [1054]: url.netloc
Out[1054]: '10.1.2.3:45678'

In [1055]: host, _, port = url.netloc.partition(':')

In [1056]: host
Out[1056]: '10.1.2.3'

In [1057]: port
Out[1057]: '45678'
```

Comment: Thanks you very much. This solution worked perfectly.

Comment: @ASaxena Glad I could help :)